# How to handle the embedded commas in hive?

Tags: hive, create-table

For example if I have a csv file with three cols,

```
sno,name,salary
 1,latha, 2000
 2,Bhavish, Chaturvedi, 3000
```

How to load this type of file in hive. I tried few of the posts from stackoverflow, but it didn't worked.

I have created a external table:

```
create external table test(
 id int,
 name string,
 salary int
) 
fields terminated by '\;' 
stored as text file;
```

and loaded the data into it. 
But when done `select * from table`, I got all `null`'s into it.

Comment: please show us what you've tried and the error message..

Comment: I have created a external table with create  external table test(id int,name string,salary int) fields terminated by '\;' stored as text file.  and loaded the data into it.  but when done select * from table, I got all null's into it.

Comment: In your data example fields terminated by `,`

Comment: @leftjoin I have done with "terminated by ," but the data is not getting inserted properly. Because in the second row we have two strings with comma separation.

Answer (score 0):

I think CSV file has column name then you have to skip header to avoid the error follow the following steps:

Step 1: Create table e.g

```
CREATE TABLE salary (sno INT, name STRING, salary INT)  
row format delimited fields terminated BY ',' stored as textfile  
tblproperties("skip.header.line.count"="1");
```

Step 2: load the CSV file into table e.g

```
load data local inpath 'file path' into table salary;
```

Step 3: Test the records

```
select * from salary;
```

Comment: hi Shambhu nath, thank you for the answer, but my requirement is if for one of the column value, if i get comma in between the string or between a long sentence , then how to handle those kind of data to be loaded into the table. example data i mentioned above. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.